# Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis equivalent for non-statisticians?

Tags: categorical-data, references

I am looking to do some categorical data analysis, but I am having a hard time following Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis. Does anyone know of good alternatives written specifically for non-statisticians?

Comment: What aspects of it make it unsuitable or what would you seek in another text that would make it understandable to scientists? I'm not sure I clearly understand the distinction at present.

Comment: Although the book contains many excellent examples to accompany the mathematical descriptions, I am having a hard time understanding all of the formulas. I am looking for something that is gentler on all of the equations and gives more of a big picture understanding.

Comment: Oh, okay. I really didn't get that from "specifically for scientists"; (indeed I wondered if it perhaps wasn't rigorous enough). You should probably edit the question to clarify what you seek.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He also published a [great applied text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471226181)

During my master's education I had a course that used the applied text and it was very easy to follow. Later during my PhD I took a higher level course using Agresti's *Categorical Data Analysis* and I had quite an easy time going through *Categorical Data Analysis* with the *Introduction* under my belt. As a bonus a lot of the examples and data sets are exactly the same in both books. So you can flip back and forth between them if you get confused.

Comment: I added some detail. To be fair the question was pretty simple.